# VB.NET For Each New Line

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, each, explode

I need help making a function that opens a file and for each new line, make a variable like `explode("\n", $var)` in PHP. I tried

```
Dim words As String = GetFileContents(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
For Each word As String In words
    Dim doHash As String = MD5(word)
    If String.Equals(doHash, hash.Text) Then
        Label2.Text = "derp"
    Else
        Label2.Text = "lol"
    End If
Next
```

but it makes each letter a new variable.

Comment: You're probably looking for [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/tabh47cf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Here's an example for explode in C#: http://www.dotnetperls.com/explode-function

Comment: Can you provide the code for `GetFileContents`?  It looks like you are returning the value as a single `String` rather than an array of `String()`.  You would need an array if you're going to iterate them.

Comment: Read up on [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) and/or [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `System.IO.File.ReadLines(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)`. That will cause the `For Each` loop to get each line separately.

Specifically:

```
For Each word As String In File.ReadLines(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
    Dim doHash As String = MD5(word)
    If String.Equals(doHash, hash.Text) Then
        Label2.Text = "derp"
    Else
        Label2.Text = "lol"
    End If
Next
```

I notice that your php example is definitely splitting on newlines, but your loop variable is called `word`. Does your file have one word per line? Doesn't matter much, but I wanted to double check that you're okay with the loop getting each *line*, not each *word* (if there's more than one word per line).

Comment: It has one word per line, yes. I will look into System.IO.File.ReadLines(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)

Comment: It's giving me a syntax error @ System.IO.File.ReadLines
System.IO is imported
-------------------
For Each File.ReadLines(word) As String In words
-------------------
is what I'm using

Comment: // Edit http://pastebin.com/0AAfwVQt
I changed to that but I get the error
"Word is not declared"

Comment: Don't add it in the foreach loop--change GetFileContents to it. Updated my answer to include complete code.

Comment: @user1328301 You need to change your `Dim words As String = GetFileContents(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)` to `Dim words As IEnumerable(Of String) = GetFileContents(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)`

Comment: It's working but now it's displaying all of the words hashed. I want it to stop when it shows that the hashed word is equal it the hash you type.
I have http://pastebin.com/UFz4RveY

Comment: @user1328301 Your original question has been answered. I would suggest marking this one as answered, and opening a new question with a specific question and the relevant details (examples, code, etc) so that it can be answered.